# Find all primes $p$ such that $x^2\equiv 10\pmod p$ has a solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all primes $p$ such that $x^2\equiv 10$ mod $p$ has a solution

So I want $\left(\frac{10}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=1$

Then $\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=1$

or $\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=-1$

for the first The quadratic residues of $5$ are $1,4$

And $2$ is a quadratic residue for primes of the form $8k+1,8k+7$

so the primes of the form $5k+1,5k+4$ and either $8k+1,8k+7$ will work

or primes which are the form $5k+3,5k+2$ and $8k+3,8k+5$

I'm not sure if it's possible to narrow this down more?

Comment: You can express these conditions modulo $40$.

Comment: You can use Chinese remainder theorem to get them modulo $40.$

Comment: You should get $p\equiv \pm 1,\pm 9,\pm 3,\pm 13\pmod{40},$ I think.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes, except for $p=2$ and $p=5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you do is correct (modulo noting that $\left(\frac{5}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{p}{5}\right)$ by Quadratic Reciprocity, which is why you are checking for quadratic residues modulo $5$) and dealing with the primes $p=2$ and $p=5$.

If $p=2$ or $p=5$, then $x^2\equiv 10\pmod{p}$ clearly has solutions.

Otherwise, your development is correct. You need either

1. $p\equiv 1,-1\pmod{5}$ and $p\equiv 1,-1\pmod{8}$; hence $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{40}$ or $p\equiv \pm 31\equiv\pm 9\pmod{40}$;
2. $p\equiv 2,-2\pmod{5}$ and $p\equiv 3,-3\pmod{8}$; hence $p\equiv \pm 27\equiv \pm13\pmod{40}$ or $p\equiv\pm37\equiv \pm3\pmod{40}$;
3. $p=2$;
4. $p=5$.

Comment: If you are going to say $\pm x\pmod{40}$ prefer the smaller $x.$ So $\pm 9$ is better than $\pm 31.$ $\pm 3$ is better than $\pm 37.$ etc. Not wrong, per se...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yeah, I was doing them in my head.

Answer (score 0):

You missed out $p=2$ and $p=5$ of course.

But other than that, you gave necessary and sufficient conditions.